# Write TraceId to logs with nlog

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nlog

I'm trying to setup my net6 project to send traces and logs to grafana loki and tempo for better observability.
I'm successfully setup sending traces to tempo using opentelemetry.instrumentation(All traces have TraceId).
Now I'm trying to get TraceId for other logs, but can't get it.
I'm using NLog.Web.AspNetCore(5.3.2) and NLog.DiagnosticSource(5.0.0) packages and as mentioned here - https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource - I can get TraceId via ${activity:property=TraceId} variable, but when I use layout like "consoleLayout": "${activity:property=TraceId} [${time} ${uppercase:${level}]} ${logger} ${aspnet-request-method}..." this variable is empty.

I did not find any information that would need to configure something else. As far as I understand, TraceID is present by default, and I only need to get it.
What I missed?

Comment: Have you tried to enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging) and looked for issues? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting (Ex. using `throwConfigExceptions="true"`)

Comment: Yes, but there are no errors. It looks like nlog just can't get this variable and leaves it empty, or this variable accessible but empty. I'm not sure, but maybe I need to configure something in the app to filling the TraceId value.

Comment: You can explicitly create your own activity-scope: `using (var newActivity = new System.Diagnostics.Activity("MyOperation").Start())` and do some logging inside the activity-scope to test.

Comment: `${aspnet-traceidentifier}` works for my asp.net core 6 (NLog.Web.AspNetCore version is 5.2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get TraceId in nlog after I have added

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(o => o
    .Configure(x => x.ActivityTrackingOptions = ActivityTrackingOptions.TraceId | ActivityTrackingOptions.SpanId));
```

Comment: Updated [README.md](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource/blob/master/README.md) with your observations around `ActivityTrackingOptions`. For others that are creating a "vanilla" host-builder, and not using the default-template with all bells and whitles enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the `TraceId` field may  contain very big number of unique values  across different log lines - an unique value per each processed request with the enabled tracing. Grafana Loki creates an unique log stream per each unique set of log fields (excluding message and timestamp fields). See [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/best-practices/). This means it will create an unique log stream per each unique `TraceId` field value. Grafana Loki stores data for every stream in a separate file. It also keeps index data per each stream in memory. This means that Grafana Loki may suffer from high number of small files and high memory usage in the case of millions of unique `StreamId` values. This is called `high cardinality issue`.

The solution is to store the `TraceId` in the message itself, and do not extract it into a separate field. Then you can use [line filters](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#line-filter-expression) for finding messages with the needed `TraceId`.

P.S. The provided solution isn't the best from usability perspective. You can store `StreamId` in a dedicated field without worrying about high cardinality issues when using alternative log management systems such as [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) or [VictoriaLogs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/) (I work on it). These systems support fast full-text search over high-cardinality fields. ElasticSearch is in widespread use, while VictoriaLogs requires 30x less RAM and 15x less disk space than ElasticSearch for the same amounts of production logs.

Comment: Thank you! I will send the TraceId as part of the message. But my problem was that I couldn't get the TraceId even as part of message.